# EF data annotations aren't "working" after targeting .NET 4.5

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I've got a project that was targeting .NET 4.0 and using EF 5.0. After changing the target framework to 4.5 (and updating the EF 5.0 reference to use the .NET 4.5 assembly), it seems like the data annotations aren't working anymore. For example:

```
[Table("ApplicationSession", Schema = "Application")]
public class ApplicationSessionEntity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("GenericSession")]
    public int GenericSessionID { get; set; }
...
```

used to work fine, but now at runtime, the `DbContext` throws an `InvalidOperationException`: `Unable to determine the principal end of an association...`.

I can add the Fluent api calls to resolve this (and it does), but then it doesn't recognize that the table is not in the "dbo" schema. Again, I know that the Fluent api can be used to resolve this, but why are the data annotations suddenly being ignored?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.ComponentModel.Annotations? The annotations were moved to this assembly in .NET Framework 4.5. What I think might be happening is that you somehow are compiling with annotations old annoations and the EF5 runtime is looking for new ones. You may press F12 on the Table and see where it goes to check this.

Comment: @Pawel I do have a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. I believe that it was required when we upgraded to EF 5.0. I have tried using the .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 versions of that assembly and they both exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Do you have somewhere a reference to EntityFramework.dll whose version is 4.4.0.0?

Comment: @Pawel Ah, I think that was it - there was still a project that was referencing the old version of EF. I did a complete uninstall/re-install of EF5.0 and that seems to have corrected the issue. Thanks for being a second set of virtual eyes!

Answer (score 8):

In .NET Framework 4.5 EF annotations were moved from EF.dll to System.ComponentModel.Annotations assembly. It seems that even though you target .NET Framework 4.5 you still have a reference to EntityFramework.dll v4.4.0.0 somewhere. As a result your classes are compiled with attributes from the 4.4.0.0 assembly. At runtime the newer EntityFramework.dll (5.0.0.0) is being used and it looks for attributes from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly. Those cannot be found since you have the ones from EF.dll 4.4.0.0 and therefore it looks like attributes are being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for this. I upgraded project from 4.0 -> 4.5 and references to EF 4.4.0.0 were hanging. I just removed reference to 4.4.0.0 and run nuget install package.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that it was moved outside the EF if you use .NET version 4.5 and above. But if you compile in .NET 4.0, you will find the `DataAnnotations` as use to be. Looking inside the code, you will find this:

```
#if NET40

namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
...
}
#endif
```

So... yes, is the same as other answers, but I want to point this out!

Happy coding!